# Vue reactivity: Computed changes data but then is not reacting to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple set-up. A "computed" is used in order to retrieve data. Following a simple condition, the data should sometimes be changed. I then hoped, that the change in the data would trigger the "computed" again. But this is not the case. My current solution is a setTimeout as this then triggers the "computed" again.

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/MH88/pen/oMbBzZ?editors=1011

Here the code-snippet.

```
//HTML Output
<div id="app" class="l-container l-vPad--mid">
  <h1>This should return 4</h1>
    <h2>getNumber: {{getNumber}}</h2>   
</div>

//Javascript logic
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    number: 5
  },
  computed: {
    getNumber() {
      var x = this.number;
      if(this.number == 5) {

          //Why is this not working?As data changes, the computed should 
          //react to it again, no?
          this.number--;

          //This solution works but there needs to be something more eloquent
          //setTimeout(() => {this.number--}, 0);

      }
      return x
    }
  }
});
```

Looking forward for some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You are currently not using computed properties in the way they are designed.

In vue we have `data` to define initial data. If you define data this way:

```
data() {
  return {
    number: 5
  }
}
```

you can access your number with `this.number`. You need to define this as a function, because this function needs to be called every time you create the component. Defining it as a function prevents the same object reference to be used across different components, causing all kinds of trouble.

A computed property is a function that computes a property based on other data. The computed property is automatically recalculated when the data it relies on changes. This works automatically, but **only if the function has no side effects**. Your computed function does have side-effects (namely it changes data on your component), which prevents this mechanism from working. An example of a computed property would be

```
computed: {
  differenceFromHundred() {
    return 100 - this.number;
  },

  numberThatCannotBeFive() {
    let x = this.number;
    if (x === 5) {
      return x - 1;
    }

    return x;
  }
}
```

If your function does have side effects, you have to use a method. Methods return a value when you call them, just like regular functions would.

```
methods: {
  // This name is misleading. You expect it to just 'get a value', but instead
  // it modifies it sometimes
  getNumber () {
    let x = this.number;
    if(this.number === 5) {
      this.number--;
    }

    return this.number
  }
}
```

---

It is unclear why you want to modify the value of number, but consider if you can use a computed property to get the output you want without changing the value of number. If you must change the value, do it in a separate function either called from a lifecycle hook or an explicit action (e.g. a click or event). You would be able to use `this.number` then as-is in the rest of your code.

Comment: I called a separate method to change the data, but as this is called within the "computed" property, the "computed" property is not re-running again.

Comment: That is because in that case your computed property still has side-effects. Your computed property should do nothing else than calculate things.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the variable 'x' which has the value '5' because you saved it using 'var x = this.number'. Don't return the saved value 'return x' instead use 'return this.number'

Just replace `return x` with `return this.number`

Following `this.number--;` is decreasing the value of number but since you are not using data properties `{{number}}` it is not being shown.

Just look at this, you will get clear. I hope.
[updated code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qybRom)

Computed properties are functions, so you should return the changed value.
Check the documentation [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thx. This of course works, but as my "real life" example is more complicated, I need  to make sure that the "computed" property is running again based on the now updated data property. With setTimeout, that works. But I hoped for some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are [passed by value](https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c). You are saving a value of `this.number` in variable `x`. This variable `x` is completely new copy. So changing `this.number` does not mean `x` also changes. So change the value of `x`.

Here is the [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/rvams1993/pen/XBXpEd?editors=1011)

Comment: thx. Although this works, I need the "computed" property to start again as my "real life" example does a lot more of computations based on the data. My goal is to make sure, that the computed property recalulates again. I achieve this with the setTimeout function, but was hoping for another solution.

Comment: @betzebube1000 , the computed property depends on `this.number`. It is called whenever the value of `this.number` changes. See this example [pen](https://codepen.io/rvams1993/pen/XBXpEd?editors=1011)